# JQuery array with checked checkboxes send into JsonResult

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day for everyone

I have a asp.net mvc4 project which include jquery. In my edit form I will try to send array of checked checkboxes by `.getJSON` and in my JsonResult i need to get my array of elements. But instead of array I receive `null` property, here is my code:

**JQuery**

I will try send 2 different functions for the sendind of my array

```
$(function () {
    var values = [];
    $(".checkboxUniversities:checked").each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".checkboxUniversities").change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/' + values, function (data) {
            var items = '<option>Select a Program</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, program) {
                items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#EducationProgramBachelorId').html(items);
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    var values = [];
    $("input[name='selectedLatUniversities']:checked").each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".checkboxUniversities").change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/' + values, function (data) {
            var items = '<option>Select a Program</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, program) {
                items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#EducationProgramBachelorId').html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

**C# code in controller**

Here is I'm tried to change declare of my `values` variable, but it's `null` still.

```
public JsonResult ProgramList(string values)
    {
        //some code
    }

public JsonResult ProgramList(string[] values)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

I was open network tab and saw that sending link looks like following:

`/Administrator/ProgramList/Uni1,Uni2,Uni3` etc. all my checked checkboxes.

I have no idea where is my mistake. Anyone have any ideas?

P.S.: My JQuery code placed inside `<script>` tag on my Razor view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send values as object in getJSON

try this

```
 var values = {};
 .....//your codes
 $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/',{"values":values}, function (data) {
 ..
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't send any values, I'm looked now on network tab, nothing requests

Comment: My values is not null, i've been check this the first time. By the way yesterday I'm somehow sended the values, but forget how :(. Sending by array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(function () {

    $(".checkboxUniversities").change(function () {
         var values = [];   // declare the array here
        $(".checkboxUniversities:checked").each(function () {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/', {
            "value": values
        }, function (data) {
             alert('success'); // for checking
           var items = '<option>Select a Program</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, program) {
                items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#EducationProgramBachelorId').html(items);
        });
    });

});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: I have edited the code try it , don forget to declare the array 'values' inside the change() as in the above code

Comment: Unfortunately it's still null

Comment: change "value": values and try

Comment: The above code is working fine for me,May be problem in your serverside coding, post it too

Comment: I didn't tell that my code isn't returned return Json, I told that get the null values, but send the whole values

Comment: @BorHunter ok, so post your server side coding

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.

My solution is next: I'm change

`ProgramList(string values)` to `ProgramList(string Id)`

and in jquery code use the next request

```
$.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/' + values , function (data) {}
```

I hope anybody help this information.

But I still isn't understand why it's working? %)

P.S.: One very smart man prompt to me that I have problems with routing, and he was right. Just change routes in `Global.asax` and everything work perfect